# Python - How do I make a dictionary inside of a text file?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm writing a program that allows the user to create a username and password. How do I write this as a dictionary into a text file, and then retrieve it when I need it? Also, if there is an easier way to do this I'm welcome to any new ideas.

Comment: is password security a concern, or is this just a toy app?

Comment: doesn't need to be any security

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text, even for insecure applications--people will often use the same password for multiple accounts and you could end up responsible for unintended intrusions. Read about password encryption: http://docs.python.org/library/crypt.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Python serialization mechanism - [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Small example:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps({'username': 'admin', 'password': '123'})
>>> s
"(dp0\nS'username'\np1\nS'admin'\np2\nsS'password'\np3\nS'123'\np4\ns."
```

Now you can easily save content of `s` to some file.  After that you can read it and decode:

```
>>> pickle.loads(s)
{'username': 'admin', 'password': '123'}
```

But this approach is not quite safe.  Don't use it for dangerous data or data that you rely on.

Check out ["Why Python Pickle is Insecure"](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure) by Nadia Alramli.

Comment: There isn't a problem with storing data that you rely on Pickle. The data is quite safe in Pickle, it's your computer that isn't safe if you're loading Pickle data from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). It's pretty great for that sort of thing, and in the standard library since 2.6.

```
import json

# write settings
with open('settings.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(settings))

# load settings1
with open('settings.json', 'r') as f:
    settings = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). It is a way to serialize your objects to a file, then retrieve it.

Also check out [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html), which will give you a more abstract feeling to the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> f = open('pass_file','w')
>>> d = {"name":"my_name", "pass":"my_pass"}
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dump(d, f)
>>> f.close()


>>> import pickle
>>> f = open('pass_file', 'r')
>>> d = pickle.load(f)
>>> d
{'name': 'my_name', 'pass': 'my_pass'}
>>>
```

And there is a faster version called [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html).